# wkhtmltopd split wide pages

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to get the PDF creation very wide sites with wkhtmltopdf to work. My problem is, that all content that does not fit onto the defined page size in width is not displayed. I am looking for a way to get wkhtmltopdf to page break if the content is wider than the page width and continue with the content on the next page.

Is there an opportunity to get this to work or do I have to create a very big PDF depending on the content size and split the pages like with Ghostscript?

Thx für hints!

Andy

Comment: Try to improve on your question.

Comment: What do you mean with improve the question?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "depending on the content size and split the pages"!?

```
  return new ActionAsPdf("Index",null
           {
             FileName = "test.pdf ",
              PageSize = Size.A4,
              PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape,
              PageMargins = { Left = 2, Right = 2 }
```

Comment: e.g. the content has a height of 650px and a width of 2500px. Width 96dpi in the width there would be the need to add a second page, like laying 2 A4 pages in landscape on the desktop side by side.
The content is build with DIVs and the left and the right contents are wrapped into DIVs again and both sides are wrapped into one DIV with a fixed size to get everything (also not visible on the screen) converted to PDF if a larger page size(like A3 or A1) is chosen.
I already added page-break-before to the css of the individual cells, but no page break is done.